# Can't Glob Several File Types

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, glob, win32com

I've researched and tested this issue for a while and can't seem to get it to work.

```
user_path
```

Is provided by the user and it contains .xlsm, ,xlsb and .xlsx file types. I'm trying to catch all of them and convert them to .csv. This works individually if I substitute the extensions:

```
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(user_path, "*.xlsm")) #xlsb, xlsm
```

I've tried the following two methods, neither of which work (win32com just tells me Excel can't access the out_folder.)

```
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(user_path, "*"))
all_files = glob.glob(user_path)
```

How can I send these two file types together with user_path?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using just `*`, `glob` matches all files AND directories under the given folder, including those you have no access to, which in your case is the `out_folder` directory, so when you iterate over the file names, make sure if they end with one of the file extensions you're looking for before you try to open them.

Since `glob` can't test for multiple file extensions at a time, it's actually better to use `os.listdir` and do the filtering of multiple file extensions on your own.

```
for filename in os.listdir(user_path):
    if any(map(filename.endswith, ('.xlsm', '.xlsb', '.xlsx'))):
        do_something(filename)
```

Or, with list comprehension,

```
all_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(user_path) if any(map(filename.endswith, ('.xlsm', '.xlsb', '.xlsx')))]
```

**Edit by the OP (actual code)**:

```
    pathlib.Path(path + '\out_folder').mkdir(parents = True, exist_ok = True)
    newpath = os.path.join(path,'out_folder')
#this is the line I can't seem to get to read both file types - it works as is.
    all_files_test = glob.glob(os.path.join(user_path, "*.xlsm")) #xlsb, xlsm

    for file in all_files_test:
        name1 = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(file)[1])[0]
```

Comment: Right - thanks, I think that's what I'm trying to do - how can I tell it to only find/use .xlsb/.xlsm rather than using the wildcard?

Comment: I've updated my answer with my recommended solution.

Comment: Ok cool thanks - that looks like it will do it - I think I was just hung up on glob/a one liner - will give it a shot - thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to get either to work fully - list comprehension fails saying nothing to concat (later on in the script). Os.listdir works but doesn't loop, only catching the first file.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing your code. Can you add your new code to your question (after mentioning that it is in response to my answer) so that I can help take a look?

Comment: Yep will do - I think this is a specific issue that I'm (hopefully) just missing something obvious.

Comment: I see your code. If you simply plugged in my code without any alteration to your existing code it certainly wouldn't work because your following loop that iterates through `all_files_test` is expecting full path names, while `os.listdir` returns just the file names, without the directory names. You simply need to join the output of `os.listdir` with your base directory, e.g. `all_files_test = [os.path.join(user_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(user_path) if any(map(filename.endswith, ('.xlsm', '.xlsb', '.xlsx')))]`.

Comment: Thank you very much - I did try tweaking it, unsuccessfully of course. I'll give this a shot, thank you very much for your time.